# Is there a way I can efficiently ungroup an Group Object on Fabric JS?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I'm currently working with fabric JS. I have group object set up with a bunch of text objects. When I resize the group, the child text object's properties do not change. I've manually tried to ungroup the group object by cloning the objects within the Group object then adding them to the canvas but the objects do not retain their properties. Any thoughts?
Much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Exactly which properties do not change? Can you set up an example (e.g. on jsfiddle) demonstrating what you need and what happens instead?

Comment: Heres an example: http://jsfiddle.net/aramajames/ZZQhb/58/ 
thanks